# What does it mean for a transition map to be smooth?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I am confused as to the difference between smooth functions and smooth transition maps between manifolds. Does the title "smooth" always and only granted to something that is infinitely differentiable?

Can someone kindly provide an example of a transition map?

Comment: Smooth is the same infinitely differentiable. Also are you asking for transition map?

Comment: Here is an example of a transition map.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)#Transition_maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ means infinitely differentiable, but for a function between arbitrary manifolds, this notion doesn't cleanly translate over. So we need transition maps, which are maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, in order to start defining the notion of a smooth function between manifolds.

(And of course a smooth transition map is also just a smooth function since it is on $\mathbb{R}^n$).